# How to customize default CSS/behaviour for <SELECT> on Web App?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I run a HTML file via WebApp that redirects to a Webpage.  On this Webpage I can't change the default CSS/behaviour of the dropdown  element.

The behaviour is scrolling text when the text is too long.

Any ideas?

This my SELECT
[image]

This is my SELECT with the dropdown menu active when I touch first item
[image]

Comment: what have you tried? please share

Comment: When text is overflown, the text scroll from right to left in the <option> element.

Comment: In Tizen you can use Tizen Advanced UI (TAU) to make UI easily ...

Comment: In the doc TAUI is not for Web App on TV.   I'm working on a TV app

Comment: i am not seeing any scroll here.... please post a clear screen shot

Comment: The selected text "Faculte" is scrolling from right to left.  Like a news ticker.
How can I style or reset the default style of this dropdown menu?